# CALayer not leaving layer in proper state

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview, caanimation

In my Mac OS X app, I'm trying to animate an NSView using a CAAnimation applied to the layer-backed view's layer using this code:

I create a CAAnimation:

```
myAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
myAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
myAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
myAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
myAnimation.duration = 3;
myAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
myAnimation.autoreverses = NO;
```

then I add it to the layer of my "myContentView" NSView:

```
[self.myContentView.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.myContentView.layer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
self.myContentView.layer.opacity = 0; //Set final value of opacity to this value
```

This actually works fine, except that every time I run the animation (triggered by a mouse click), I start by making the NSView's parent window visible and set it's alphaValue to 1, the myContentView shows for a fraction of a second at the last opacity value it was displaying when I called the above code and it hit removeAllAnimations.

It is like if the presentationLayer stays in cache and is redisplayed before the animation kicks in.

If I let the animation completely finish (by holding the mouse button down longer until it completely fades out), then the next time around, all is fine. It is only when it gets interrupted mid-way by removeAllAnimations that it seems to stick around.

I tried setting the opacity to 0 before every call to make the window visible, but that fails too. I have no idea why the layer is not set to an opacity of 0 even when I interrupt the animation.

Any suggestions? What am I not doing right?

Just to be clear, I'm not adding layers myself, just setting the NSView to be layer-backed.

My CAAnimation never calls anything on my controller if I set it as a delegate either... which is weird too. I must be doing something wrong for sure.

What is being drawn in the NSView is done programmatically in it's drawRect: method, using a bezier shape.

I found a working workaround. If I remove my view from the window's contentView just before displaying the said Window, and add it back just after, then, the ghost of the previous animation" seems to get flushed somehow and does not appear.